# Windows DNS - Reverse resolution not working for public IPs

Tags: windows-server-2016, reverse-dns

I was troubleshooting an internal application when I discovered that the reverse lookup only works for internal private IPs.

Is there a way I could configure our Microsoft DNS servers (Win2016) to use the forwarder servers to resolve every rDNS requests not found locally?

The final goal is to get at least the DNS entries of our public IP addresses.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You wrongly assume this is a problem with your DNS. Reverse DNS is always done at level of a /24 - no way to do it lower - and it is your provider's responsibility to provide proper reverse mapping. There is nothing you can do if they do not do it - except talking to their support.

If you have a /24 they can delegate that to your DNS.

If not, or if you do not want delegation, their support should be able to update their DNS and / or they may have a web interface or API to update their servers.

There is also a chance they never cared about that and are just incompetent.